# How can I set several MQTT callbacks and subscribe to multiple topics in one piece of code?

Tags: callback, mqtt, subscribe

I am quite new with MQTT. I am working on a project involving a Pycom board (Sipy). On a breadboard, I have a temperature and a weight sensors which I am reading the values. Those are compared to the values the user can chose using two slider widgets on an IOT platform (Adafruit IO). For instance, if the temperature value chosen by the user is higher than the one measured by the sensor, the msg ''Value higher'' is printed on my REPL consol, and same for the weight. For that, I coded two callbacks functions (named sub_weight and sub_temp). Then, I use client.set_callback(sub_cb_weight) and client.set_callback(sub_cb_temp). However, it seems to me that it is only the second callback written that is taken into consideration, as if the first one was pressed. I have the same problem when I try to subscribe to both topics. My question then was : is it possible to subscribe to more than one topic and also to set two callbacks so that I can have two answers ?

```
from umqtt import MQTTClient 
import ubinascii 
import micropython 
from machine import Pin,ADC,I2C
import network
from network import WLAN
import onewire
from onewire import OneWire,Ds
AIO_SERVER = "io.adafruit.com"
AIO_PORT = 1883
AIO_USER = "username"
AIO_KEY = "key"
AIO_CLIENT_ID = ubinascii.hexlify(machine.unique_id())
client = MQTTClient(AIO_CLIENT_ID, AIO_SERVER, AIO_PORT, AIO_USER, AIO_KEY)

wlan=WLAN(mode=WLAN.STA)
pw='mypw'
nets=wlan.scan()
for net in nets:
    if net.ssid == 'myssid':
        wlan.connect(net.ssid,auth=(None,pw),timeout=5000)
        if wlan.isconnected() == True:
            print('Connected')
        else:
            print('Not connected')
client.connect()

AIO_WEIGHT_FEED = "username/feeds/weight"


def press_sensor():
    adc=machine.ADC()
    apin=adc.channel(pin='G5')
    p=(apin()*700/4095)
    return p

def sub_cb_weight(topic_full, pressed_full):
    print((topic_full, pressed_full))
    p=press_sensor()
    while True:
      if msg <= str(p).encode('ascii'):
          print('You chose a lower weight')
      else:
          print('You chose a higher one')
          time.sleep(3)

client.set_callback(sub_cb_weight)
client.subscribe(AIO_WEIGHT_FEED)
print("Connected to %s, subscribed to %s topic" % (AIO_SERVER, AIO_CONTROL_FEED_CALIB_FULL))

AIO_CONTROL_TEMP = "username/feeds/Temperature control"

def temp_sensor():
    ow = OneWire(Pin('P22',mode=Pin.IN,pull=Pin.PULL_UP))
    temp = Ds(ow)
    t=temp.read_temp()
    t=t/100
    t=int(t)
    return t

def sub_cb_temp(topic, msg): 
    print((topic, msg)) 
    v=temp_sensor()
    while True:
      if msg <= str(v).encode('ascii'):
          print('You chose a lower temperature')
      else:
          print('You chose a higher one')
          time.sleep(3)


client.set_callback(sub_cb_temp)
client.subscribe(AIO_CONTROL_TEMP)
print("Connected to %s, subscribed to %s topic" % (AIO_SERVER, AIO_CONTROL_TEMP))
while 1: 
     client.check_msg()
```

For example, in the piece of code I've attached below, my device will only subscribe to the temperature feed and prints messages linked to this value. The sensor values are well being read and compared though. Here's the link of the MQTT module I'm using : https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/blob/master/umqtt.simple/umqtt/simple.py. I can connect properly to the platform.
I am not sure if I'm being clear right now but I can provide you with further information if needed.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This library lets you setup one callback to handle all subscribed messages. You can use the `topic` parameter in the callback to determine how to handle the message.

e.g. register a single callback such as

```
def callback(topic, msg): 
    print((topic, msg))
    if topic == b"username/feeds/Temperature control":
        sub_cb_temp(topic, msg)
    else
        sub_cb_weight(topic, msg)
```

Your current callbacks are also not multi-threaded and enter a busy while loop. They will only process the first message (on one of these topics) that it receives and they also don't allow a publish acknowledgement to be sent by the library. You will need to use threads to handle both topics simultaneously.